# How to retrieve directories name using ant

Tags: ant

I have directory named "BACKUP". Is there any way to retrieve all the folder and files present in that directory using ant build script.

Comment: Can you give us more details? What you want to do with that list, how do you want to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files: `<fileset dir="BACKUP" />`

Folders: `<dirset dir="BACKUP" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) type:

`<fileset dir="BACKUP"/>`